# IRS Form FBAR FinCEN 114

Tags: united-states, fbar

The situation is I have a foreign account but it is for my business. It was there just as a flow in the middle to pay the foreign suppliers. It is just a regular foreign checking account under my name. My business was a sole owner small business and not easy to open a business account in the designated country at the time. The questions are

1. so I believe it should be under "No Financial Interest Account Information." section ?
2. if yes for #1, can the filler and account owner be the same in this case ? what should I put in 43 Filer's title with this owner ? (thinking of "Self")

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't that form also require you to report the business you own?

Answer (score 1):

> so I believe it should be under "No Financial Interest Account Information." section ?

Why? It's your account in your name. From legal perspective it is your personal account and you have financial interest in it.